# Android Studio 1.5.1 slow build + error with sdk manager

Tags: android-studio, build, sdk

Some of my projects take 5-10 minutes to build! without any change of code on my part...

Also, when entering the sdk manager, this is what happens:

[image: sdk loading gets stuck...]

[image: after 30 min]

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not the only person this is happening to, gonna leave this post.

My IP was changed suddenly at my workplace, so I needed to provide server permissions for the new IP address. simple.